# Disable showing the mouse movement in VNC server

Tags: vnc

Here's the scenario:
vnc server - Windows XP
vnc viewer - Linux

When I connect to my vnc server, I am able to see the mouse / keyboard movement at the vnc server from my vnc viewer. For example, when I click on something at the vnc viewer, I see the same thing at the vnc server.

Is there a way to disable the mouse / keyboard movement (i.e. put the vnc server in a 'blank' mode, so that whatever I do on the vnc viewer, it will not be reflected on the server side)? I mean the easiest way would be to just turn off the monitor... but I'm not sure this can be with a laptop.

Comment: This isn't programming related. Try http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its part of the VNC Viewer input options
http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvncviewer.html#Input

Comment: From how I understand this documentation, this basically set the vnc viewer in a read-only mode. This is not what I want since I want to still be able to use the vnc viewer. 

Imagine when I am moving my mouse at the vnc viewer screen, I do not want the movement of the mouse to be seen in the vnc server side. Hope I explained this better.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood!  You can't do that!  VNC viewer basically gives you control of the server's mouse and keyboard, its not like VNC produces an 'extra' pointer that you can somehow hide - there is only one pointer.  If you could hide the pointer on the server you wouldn't see it on the viewer either - it would be invisible!

Comment: @reach4thelasers, that does not seem accurate. I am experiencing the same problem with RealVNC. When I connect to the server I see my own mousepointer in the viewer and the server mouse arrow as well. Both are **not** synced and it is quite annoying. I did not have that before so it must be possible to disable showing the mouse pointer on the server side or to at least have them sync. In fact the server mouse arrow does not go anywhere it just sits at a fixed location while a small dot (my viewer/client side cursor) moves with my client side mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings on your host, and click on expert. Search for `AcceptPointerEvents` and set the option to `False`.